# Extra lines in polygon in ArcScene vs ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have a polygon of a park boundary in ArcMap. It is a single line around the perimeter of the park. When I display that same polygon in ArcScene, it looks the same. However, when I drape that layer on the DEM (using "float layer on a custom surface"), all sorts of extra lines appear in the polygon. I have clipped the screen below to show a) the image straight out of ArcMap with the polygon on a DEM layer,

a) [image: Polygon in ArcMap]

b) the polygon in ArcScene without adding Base Height information

[image]

and c) the polygon in ArcScene once I have added "Base Height" information
[image]

What is going on with this?

Comment: Convert it to polyline, draping polygons over terrain is very challenging task